# Задача из Проекта Эйлера: вроде решил, ответ по примеру верный(если брать 4 последовательных числа), а вот если взять 13 чисел, то неверно

Tags: java

Условие:

Наибольшее произведение четырех последовательных цифр в нижеприведенном 1000-значном числе равно 9 × 9 × 8 × 9 = 5832.

73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934
96983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843
85861560789112949495459501737958331952853208805511
12540698747158523863050715693290963295227443043557
66896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113
62229893423380308135336276614282806444486645238749
30358907296290491560440772390713810515859307960866
70172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776
65727333001053367881220235421809751254540594752243
52584907711670556013604839586446706324415722155397
53697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482
83972241375657056057490261407972968652414535100474
82166370484403199890008895243450658541227588666881
16427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586
17866458359124566529476545682848912883142607690042
24219022671055626321111109370544217506941658960408
07198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188
84580156166097919133875499200524063689912560717606
05886116467109405077541002256983155200055935729725
71636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450

Найдите наибольшее произведение тринадцати последовательных цифр в данном числе.

Повторюсь, если взять 4 числа, как в примере, то ответ сходится, но если взять 13 чисел, то выдает ответ: 2091059712, а верный: 23514624000;
Прошу помощи(
Вот мой код:

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String fckstr = "73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934\r\n" + 
            "96983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843\r\n" + 
            "85861560789112949495459501737958331952853208805511\r\n" + 
            "12540698747158523863050715693290963295227443043557\r\n" + 
            "66896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113\r\n" + 
            "62229893423380308135336276614282806444486645238749\r\n" + 
            "30358907296290491560440772390713810515859307960866\r\n" + 
            "70172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776\r\n" + 
            "65727333001053367881220235421809751254540594752243\r\n" + 
            "52584907711670556013604839586446706324415722155397\r\n" + 
            "53697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482\r\n" + 
            "83972241375657056057490261407972968652414535100474\r\n" + 
            "82166370484403199890008895243450658541227588666881\r\n" + 
            "16427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586\r\n" + 
            "17866458359124566529476545682848912883142607690042\r\n" + 
            "24219022671055626321111109370544217506941658960408\r\n" + 
            "07198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188\r\n" + 
            "84580156166097919133875499200524063689912560717606\r\n" + 
            "05886116467109405077541002256983155200055935729725\r\n" + 
            "71636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450";
    char[] mas = fckstr.toCharArray(); // массив из строки
    int[] mas2 = new int[fckstr.length()];args // создание массива для чисел
    int c, d = 0;
    for(int j = 0; j < fckstr.length(); j++) {
    mas2[j] = Character.getNumericValue(mas[j]); // перевод чисел из char в int
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < fckstr.length() - 12; i++) { // для 13 последовательных чисел
        c = mas2[i] * mas2[i + 1] * mas2[i + 2] * mas2[i + 3] * mas2[i + 4] 
                * mas2[i + 5] * mas2[i + 6] * mas2[i + 7] * mas2[i + 8]
                * mas2[i + 9] * mas2[i + 10] * mas2[i + 11] * mas2[i + 12];
        d = calc(c,d); // нахождение самого большого значения
    }
    System.out.println(d);
}
public static int calc(int a, int b) { //определяет большее значение
    int max;
    if(b > a) max = b;
    else max = a;
    return max;
  }
}
```

Если хотите проверить первый пример, то вам надо в цикле для последовательных чисел изменить - 12 на -3; а количество перемножаемых ячеек массива сократить до  c = mas2[i] * mas2[i + 1] * mas2[i + 2] * mas2[i + 3]

Comment: респект за название строки))

Comment: Я бы для начала убрал "\r\n". Смысла в них никакого нет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String fckstr = "73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934"
                + "96983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843"
                + "85861560789112949495459501737958331952853208805511"
                + "12540698747158523863050715693290963295227443043557"
                + "66896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113"
                + "62229893423380308135336276614282806444486645238749"
                + "30358907296290491560440772390713810515859307960866"
                + "70172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776"
                + "65727333001053367881220235421809751254540594752243"
                + "52584907711670556013604839586446706324415722155397"
                + "53697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482"
                + "83972241375657056057490261407972968652414535100474"
                + "82166370484403199890008895243450658541227588666881"
                + "16427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586"
                + "17866458359124566529476545682848912883142607690042"
                + "24219022671055626321111109370544217506941658960408"
                + "07198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188"
                + "84580156166097919133875499200524063689912560717606"
                + "05886116467109405077541002256983155200055935729725"
                + "71636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450";

        System.out.println(calculate(fckstr, 13));

    }

    public static long calculate(String fckstr, int numb) {        
        long result = 0, tmp = 1;
        for (int k = 0; k < numb; k++) {
            for (int i = k; i < fckstr.length(); i++) {
                result=Math.max(tmp*=Character.getNumericValue(fckstr.charAt(i)), result);
                if ((i-k)%numb==0) tmp=1;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

}
```

Ваша проблема в символе \r\n, когда вы распознаете  символ, то получаете здесь отрицательное значение - это -1, отсюда некорректный результат

Answer (score 2):

Я решил сделать по своему и вот верное решение:

Что я сделал:
1 - Убрал `/r/n`, т.к. это нам не нужно .
2 - В отдельном методе `calculate` я принимаю число в виде строки и сколько последовательных чисел будет перемножаться .
3 - `For-loop` начинается от 0 и кончается длиной числа минус сколько чисел в ряд мы перемножаем
4 - Создаем второй `for-loop`, в котором перемножаем `N` последовательных чисел:
`tempResult *= Character.getNumericValue(line.charAt(j));` .
5 - сравниваем `tempResult` с `result` и в конце выводим `result`, что будет являться наибольшим произведением `N` чисел

```java
public class stackover {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String fckstr = "73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934" +
                "96983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843" +
                "85861560789112949495459501737958331952853208805511" +
                "12540698747158523863050715693290963295227443043557" +
                "66896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113" +
                "62229893423380308135336276614282806444486645238749" +
                "30358907296290491560440772390713810515859307960866" +
                "70172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776" +
                "65727333001053367881220235421809751254540594752243" +
                "52584907711670556013604839586446706324415722155397" +
                "53697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482" +
                "83972241375657056057490261407972968652414535100474" +
                "82166370484403199890008895243450658541227588666881" +
                "16427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586" +
                "17866458359124566529476545682848912883142607690042" +
                "24219022671055626321111109370544217506941658960408" +
                "07198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188" +
                "84580156166097919133875499200524063689912560717606" +
                "05886116467109405077541002256983155200055935729725" +
                "71636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450";
        calculate(fckstr, 4);
        calculate(fckstr, 13);
    }

    private static void calculate(String line, int number){
        long result = 0;
        long tempResult;
        for (int i = 0; i <= line.length() - number; i++) {
            tempResult = 1;
            for(int j = i; j < i + number; j++){
                tempResult *= Character.getNumericValue(line.charAt(j));
            }
            if(tempResult >= result){
                result = tempResult;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Result = " + result);
    }
}
```

Comment: Такс, почти во всем разобрался:
 Character.getNumericValue(line.charAt(j)); Как я понял, это обращение к строке, откуда вытаскивается число под соответствующим индексом?
*Большое спасибо*

Answer (score 0):

Ваша ошибка в первоначальном варианте была была связана с неправильным типом данных для вычисления "c". int.MaxValue=2147483647 < 23514624000, которое Вы хотели получить.
Если бы Вы использовали не int, а ulong или long, как в последнем варианте, то и первоначальный вариант "сработал" бы (наверное :) ).